# Determine virtual & physical memory sizes given addresses and offset

Tags: memory

```
Virtual address  :   0101110101001100 (last 8 bits is offset)
physical address : 110011110001001100 (last 8 bits is offset)
```

1) How many virtual and physical addresses are there?

2) How many pages and how many page frames are there?

3) Whats the size of the page in bits?

The answers should be fairly easy but I found various solutions and got confused.

1) I assume there are 2^16 virtual addresses and 2^18 physical

2) 2^16 pages but how many page frames?

3) 2^8 bytes or 2^8 bits ?

Comment: Post the solutions you come up with and see what people think

Comment: Generally people do not answer homework questions if no personal investment is present in the question. How can we determine the number of addresses given a number of bits to address them?   What is an offset and how is it related to page size?  This should help you to find the solution.

Comment: 1) I assume there are 2^16 virtual addresses  and 2^18 physical
2) 2^16 pages but how many page frames?
3) 2^8 bytes or 2^8 bits ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) is correct 2^16 VA and 2^18 PA

Pages is the terminology for virtual addresses and page frames for physical addresses.

Offset indicates byte address within a given page (or page frame). The remaining in the address indicates a mean to address a page. And the adresse of any byte is formed by concatenating the address of its page and its address within a page.

If you have 8 bits offset and 16 bits virtual address, a page address is on 8 bits and there are 2^8 pages. Similarly for physical addresses, page frame addresses are on 10 bits and there are 2^10 page frames.

And page or page frame size is 2^8 bytes (addresses always refer to byte).